# Python beautifulsoup with regex

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the `poster` value of the below JSON object on an html page. I can do this in PHP but having trouble in python

Sample of HTML page

```
  <script>
        (function(window, sabaPlayer) {
            var options = JSON.parse('{"poster":"https:\/\/static.cdn.asset.example.com\/avt\/14ewrwer33-6793-b__35454e466.jpg","plugins":{"sabaPlayerPlugin":{"uuid":"ulF31","duration":366,"logo":"",
```

PHP  (works)  This is returned `https://static.cdn.asset.example.com/avt/14ewrwer33-6793-b__35454e466.jpg`

```
$txt = $html;

$matches = [];
preg_match('/JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)/iu', $txt, $matches);
$parsed = json_decode($matches[1]);

$poster = $parsed->poster;
```

With Python nothing is returned.  There is page.content

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
test = soup.find_all(re.compile("/JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)/iu"))
print(test)
```

How do i solve?

Comment: Post a sample of `html` or `page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find_all(re.compile("/JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)/iu"))` searches **tags** that match to the regex. Obviously there are none.

Also note that you are not using the correct syntax for regex in Python. There is no need for the leading `/` (it's actually part of the regex), and the flags should not be part of the regex.

You have 2 options:

- First find all the `script` tags, then try to match the regex each tag's text:

  ```
  string = ''' <script>
      (function(window, sabaPlayer) {
          var options = JSON.parse('{"poster":"a poster"}')
          }
          </script>'''

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import json
  import re

  soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')

  script_tags = soup.find_all('script')
  for tag in script_tags:
      match = re.search("JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)", tag.text)
      if match:
          print(json.loads(match.group(1))['poster'])
  # a poster
  ```
- Use the regex over the entire page content, no need for beautifulsoup. I think this is the less preferable option.

  ```
  string = ''' <script>
  (function(window, sabaPlayer) {
      var options = JSON.parse('{"poster":"a poster"}')
      }
      </script>'''

  import re
  import json

  match = re.search("JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)", string)
  if match:
      print(json.loads(match.group(1))['poster'])
  # a poster
  ```